# Android Facebook SDK How To Update Notification

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

I am trying to update a notification via the Facebook ADK. The documentation says this:

"You can mark a notification as read by issuing an HTTP POST request to /NOTIFICATION_ID?unread=0 with the manage_notifications permission."

I know how to read the notifications with the graph path "me/notifications", but I am unsure of the code to do a POST to mark a notification as being read.

```
Facebook facebook = ......."Authorized Facebook Object"
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
```

...
How do I add in the "/NOTIFICATION_ID?unread=0" parameters?
...

```
String result = facebook.request("me/notifications", parameters, "POST");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok...I figured this one out:

```
Facebook facebook = ...
String unreadParameter = "0";   
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, accessToken);
parameters.putString("unread", unreadParameter);
String result = facebook.request(notificationID, parameters, "POST");
```

The Graph Path needs to only be the "NOTIFICATION_ID" and nothing else...I was putting in "me/notifications/NOTIFICATION_ID" and other variations.

I hope that others find this helpful.